Using C functions inside .asm files (MASM)
I've tried to use KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel which is apparently located inside hal.lib based on MS docs. Even if not it's still inside ntoskrnl.lib.
Even if I include the .inc and .lib files, nothing happens I get the 'unresolved external symbol KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel referenced inside ...'
Here's what I tried
INCLUDE C:\masm32\include\ntoskrnl.inc
INCLUDE C:\masm32\include\hal.inc

INCLUDELIB C:\masm32\lib\ntoskrnl.lib
INCLUDELIB C:\masm32\lib\hal.lib

EXTERN KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel:PROC

PUBLIC TestFunction
TestFunction PROC
    CALL KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel
    RET
TestFunction ENDP

END


yet I still got the unresolved external symbol error
EDIT: here is my VCXPROJ file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>x64</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
            <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
            <Platform>x64</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <ProjectGuid>{96189790-291B-46B6-8818-C4716A65E93C}</ProjectGuid>
        <TemplateGuid>{1bc93793-694f-48fe-9372-81e2b05556fd}</TemplateGuid>

        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>

        <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''">x64</Platform>
        <RootNamespace>Necrobyte</RootNamespace>
        <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>$(LatestTargetPlatformVersion)</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
        <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
        <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
        <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
        <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
        <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <TargetVersion>Windows10</TargetVersion>
        <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
        <PlatformToolset>WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0</PlatformToolset>
        <ConfigurationType>Driver</ConfigurationType>
        <DriverType>KMDF</DriverType>
        <DriverTargetPlatform>Universal</DriverTargetPlatform>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
    <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
        <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    </ImportGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
        <OutDir>..\bin\</OutDir>
        <!--<IntDir>..\bin\$(Configuration)\Junk\</IntDir>-->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
        <DebuggerFlavor>DbgengKernelDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
        <OutDir>..\bin\</OutDir>
        <!--<IntDir>..\bin\$(Configuration)\Junk\</IntDir>-->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <DriverSign>
            <FileDigestAlgorithm>sha256</FileDigestAlgorithm>
        </DriverSign>
        <Link>
            <AdditionalDependencies>$(DDK_LIB_PATH)ntoskrnl.lib;$(DDK_LIB_PATH)netio.lib;$(DDK_LIB_PATH)hal.lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\km\x64\hal.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
        <DriverSign>
            <FileDigestAlgorithm>sha256</FileDigestAlgorithm>
        </DriverSign>
        <Link>
            <AdditionalDependencies>$(DDK_LIB_PATH)ntoskrnl.lib;$(DDK_LIB_PATH)netio.lib;$(DDK_LIB_PATH)hal.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
        </Link>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FilesToPackage Include="$(TargetPath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile Include="..\src\**\*.c"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <MASM Include="..\src\**\*.asm" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
</Project>


You included the ntoskrnl.lib twice instead of the hal.lib.

@Jester I just noticed that, my bad. But still
no matter what I do, nothing works. even if I includelib hal.lib and include hal.inc

Your project is using DDK_LIB_PATH but your asm uses C:\masm32\lib. Try fixing that.

That doesn't change, both of the lib files are the same, I used IDA to look at the contents and none of them have any functions inside?

not exist any KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel in hal.lib (x86). exist __imp__KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel@0.  and this is not PROC. this is pointer. so all is wrong. declaration must be EXTERN __imp__KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel@0:DWORD (for x86 of course only). and call __imp__KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel@0

How did you find that out? and I got error A2024: invalid operand size for instruction
is there a way to call it on x64
